# Savings Account

Tags: savings

I have a question about a savings account I have with Wells Fargo. I have had the account my whole childhood, and am turning 18 in less than 2 weeks. I am pretty sure it is a "minor by" savings account, because I was not able to withdraw money...I could typically deposit it, but was always told the parent usually had to be present to deposit. I asked my father about taking the money out once I turn 18, and he said I could do it...so I was wondering what I would need then to be able to take the money out??? Do I need an I.D. or anything?

Comment: Have you contacted Wells Fargo to ask them?

Answer (score 1):

By law, if the account was a "minor by", also called a "custodian" account, it automatically transfers to you once you reach the age of majority in your state, which I gather from your post is 18. Once you turn 18, all you should need to withdraw money is a state or federal government issued photo-ID, like a drivers license or a military ID, same as you would need for any other bank withdrawal at a teller. Or, an ATM card & PIN if you wanted to use an ATM.